# How can I know if the user took screenshot of my app?

Tags: android, screenshot

My app represents funny sentences that my users upload, and in order to know which sentences are better I want to know if the user has taken a screenshot. The only related thing I found is from Google Maps. Anyone know how to make a "screenshot listener" or which method it invokes? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is by creating a class which is implementing [FileObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html). Then add listener when you are loading activity ( by using onStart() activity's method) and remove listener when you are going out of your activity (by using onStop() activity's method).

Once you get FileObserver event, you have to be sure that is a picture creation.

Note that this method is not 100% safe but it's simple to make it works !